# How to Fourier Transform $\frac{\sin(x)^2}{x^2}$ without Contour Integration.

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

In our lecture we need to Fourier transform $\frac{\sin(x)^2}{x^2}$, i.e. compute the integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm e^{-iy x}\frac{\sin(x)^2}{x^2} \mathrm dx$$ 
Since it's a lecture on partial differential equations and not complex analysis, I don't think contour integration can be the solution here. I already tried to rewrite $\sin x$ getting

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{4x^2} (\mathrm e^{ix(2-y)}-2\mathrm e^{-ixy}+\mathrm e^{-ix(y+2)})\mathrm dx$$

but now I'm still stuck with the computation of something like $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm e^{-ixy}}{x^2}\mathrm dx$$
Any ideas or hints are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The primitive function cannot be expressed in terms of "normal" functions. I think based on the course, the FT of $\frac{sin^2(x)}{x^2}$ can be accepted as a fact or can be done by some complex analysis/multivariable analysis/vector analysis stuff. Or there might even be some real analysis stuff, like in the case if $\exp(-x^2)$.

Comment: Maybe one needs to see it as a tempered distribution, like when calculating the Fourier transform of the delta distribution or the identity function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trivial from the Inversion Theorem for the Fourier transform.

**Note** that below I leave out all the $\pi$'s and $2\pi$'s; to actually get the right answer you'll need to look up some definitions and insert a few constants.

Note first that $\frac{\sin(x)}x=\hat f(x)$, where $f=\frac12\chi_{[-1,1]}$.
So $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}=\widehat{f*f}$. Since all our functions are even the inversion theorem shows that the Fourier transform of $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$ is $f*f$, which you can easily calculate. (In fact $f*f$ should be a triangle function supported on $[-2,2]$, which agrees with the other answer.)

Comment: Ah genius, so simple, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Due to parity it is enough to compute
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)\cos(xs)}{x^2}\,dx \stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\lim_{M\to +\infty}\int_{-M}^{M}\frac{\sin^2(x)\cos(xs)}{x^2}\,dx $$
and by integration by parts the RHS equals
$$ \lim_{M\to +\infty}\int_{-M}^{M}\frac{\frac{1}{2}\cos(xs)-\frac{1}{4}\cos(x(s+2))-\frac{1}{4}\cos(x(s-2))}{x^2}\,dx $$
or
$$ \lim_{M\to +\infty}\int_{-M}^{M}\frac{\frac{s+2}{4}\sin(x(s+2))+\frac{s-2}{4}\sin(x(s-2))+\frac{s}{2}\sin(xs)}{x}\,dx $$
where we may exploit the standard result
$$ \forall \alpha\in\mathbb{R},\qquad \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(\alpha x)}{x}\,dx = \pi\,\text{Sign}(\alpha) $$
to get:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)\cos(xs)}{x^2}\,dx =\frac{\pi}{4}\left[|s-2|+|s+2|-2|s|\right]. $$
The RHS is a piecewise-linear function, supported on $[-2,2]$, going from $0$ to $\pi$ on $[-2,0]$ and from $\pi$ to $0$ on $[0,2]$. Not by chance, it is a multiple of the convolution between $\mathbb{1}_{(-1,1)}$ and itself.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "due to parity", more precisely why you can leave out the exponential function?

Comment: @DeltaChief He doesn't leave out the exp. Simply you write the exponential as i Sine + Cosine, then split the integral into the two terms. The first one will be an odd function, hence the integration between symmetrical and opposite extrema is zero. What remains is the piece with the Cosine.

Comment: @DeltaChief: the Fourier transform of an even function is a Fourier *cosine* transform, by just enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto -x$.

Comment: ah ok, thanks, now I understand what happened to the exp. Can you also maybe explain more how exactly you did the integration by parts? I don't see how you arrived at the given formula. (and was the M introduced to do the integration by parts, or what purpose does it serve?)

Comment: @DeltaChief: symmetric integration is introduced to ensure convergence. For instance, $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not a Lebesgue integrable function over $\mathbb{R}$. Integration by parts is performed by integrating $\frac{1}{x^2}$ and by differentiating the numerator.

Comment: Ok, now I get it, thanks for the help!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'm sorry I have to ask again, but could you maybe give me another step in the integration by parts. I only get $\lim_{M\to +\infty}\int_{-M}^{M}\frac{-\sin (xs)\sin ^2 (x) s +2 \cos (xs) \sin (x) \cos (x)}{x}\,dx$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-\ic yx}\,{\sin^{2}\pars{x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x}}  =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-\ic yx}\
\overbrace{\bracks{{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic kx}\,\dd k}}
^{\ds{\sin\pars{x} \over x}}\
\overbrace{\bracks{{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic qx}\,\dd q}}
^{\ds{\sin\pars{x} \over x}}\ \,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 4}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\
\overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\pars{-y + k + q}x\ic}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{2\pi\,\delta\pars{-y + k + q}}}\ \dd k\,\dd q =
{1 \over 2}\,\pi\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\delta\pars{k - \bracks{y - q}}
\dd k\,\dd q
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\pi\int_{-1}^{1}\bracks{-1 < y - q < 1}\,\dd q =
{1 \over 2}\,\pi\int_{-1}^{1}\bracks{y - 1 < q < y + 1}\,\dd q
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\pi\braces{%
\bracks{y - 1 < -1}\bracks{-1 < y + 1 < 1}\int_{-1}^{y + 1}\dd q +
\bracks{-1 < y - 1 < 1}\bracks{y + 1 > 1}\int_{y - 1}^{1}\dd q}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\pi\braces{\vphantom{\Large A}%
\bracks{y < 0}\bracks{-2 < y < 0}\pars{y + 2} +
\bracks{0 < y < 2}\bracks{y > 0}\pars{2 - y}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\pi\braces{\vphantom{\Large A}%
\bracks{-2 < y < 0}\pars{2 - \verts{y}} +
\bracks{0 < y < 2}\bracks{y > 0}\pars{2 - \verts{y}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\pars{1 - {1 \over 2}\,\verts{y}}\,\pi
\bracks{\vphantom{\large A}\verts{y} < 2}\bracks{\vphantom{\large A}y \not= 0}}
\end{align}

> Note that the above result $\ds{\to \pi}$ as $\ds{y \to 0}$ !!!.

[image]